# Finding the number of isomorphisms which exist between $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm just not sure how to go about this, could you help me to find the method of doing this? Suppose we have a field $\mathbb{Z}_{3} = \{0,1,2\}$ and we take the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{2}$ (pairs of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$). How do we find the number of isomorphic maps existing from $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{2} \to $ $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{2}$.

Thanks! Lauren

Comment: Are we talking about the group $\mathbb{Z}_3$? or the ring? That is, is there just an addition going on, or is there a multiplication too?

Comment: Does that help? $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is a field and $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{2}$ is a vector space over that field?

Comment: Yes, that's what we needed to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us ignore the vector space structure of $\Bbb Z_3^2$ for now; the abelian group structure is really what determines isomorphisms. If you're not sure about that, see below.

> Suppose we do find a map $\phi: \Bbb Z_3^2 \to \Bbb Z_3^2$ that's an isomorphism of the underlying abelian groups; that is, $\phi(g + h) = \phi(g) + \phi(g)$. Then, as we can view scalar multiplication as repeated addition in this space, we have $\phi(cg) = c\phi(g)$ for scalars $c \in \Bbb Z_3$; the vector space structure is preserved as well, and $\phi$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, not just abelian groups).

Since $\Bbb Z_3^2 = \{(x_1, x_2): x_i \in \Bbb Z_3\}$, as an abelian group it's generated by the elements $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$. It's also a general fact that an isomorphism must map a generating set to a generating set; isomorphisms preserve every piece of algebraic structure a group has, and a generating set is part of this group structure.

So, if you could figure out how many generating sets of size $2$ the group $\Bbb Z_3^2$ has, then you've enumerated the number of isomorphisms: Each must map a generating set of size $2$ to a generating set of size $2$, and each isomorphism is completely determined by where it sends a generating set. This is the sense in which we're talking about bases for a vector space; they're precisely the generating sets of the underlying abelian group!

Let's say we've picked some nonzero $(a, b) \in \Bbb Z_3^2$. By itself, it merely generates a cyclic subgroup of size $3$; that is, $\langle (a, b) \rangle = \{(a, b), (2a, 2b), (0, 0)\}$. But when we add some group element that isn't in $\langle (a, b) \rangle$ to our generating set, then we'll have a set that generates all of $\Bbb Z_3^2$ (convince yourself of this; informally, or with a proof). For example, $\{(1, 2), (1, 1)\}$ generates the group.

So a unique isomorphism may be obtained by:

- Choosing any nonidentity element in $\Bbb Z_3^2$ (which viewed as nonzero vectors in the space), call it $g$. (How many ways are there to choose such a $g$?)
- Choose any element in $\Bbb Z_3^2$ that's not in $\langle g \rangle$ (How many ways are there to choose such an $h$?)
- Define a map $\phi$ by sending $(1, 0) \overset{\phi}{\mapsto} g,\quad (0, 1) \overset{\phi}{\mapsto} h$. By the remarks earlier, $\phi$ is automatically an isomorphism $\phi: \Bbb Z_3^2 \to \Bbb Z_3^2$.

The map $\phi$ is uniquely determined by the pair $g$ and $h$, and every isomorphism $\Bbb Z_3^2 \to \Bbb Z_3^2$ arises in this fashion. Count the pairs $g$ and $h$ satisfying the above, and you've counted your isomorphisms.

Comment: @psj36  Lauren is looking for vector space isomorphisms. Check the comments he made on the first answer

Comment: I did indeed notice, in particular that the OP hadn't made the connection between their problem, and invertible transformations. Do you think I haven't been explicit enough about why an isomorphism of the underlying abelian groups is necessarily an isomorphism of vector spaces?

Comment: No nothing to have with this. The OP  said : Unfortunately I haven't come across automorphisms of groups so I'm not sure what this means. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

As a vector space\group : you should compute $\vert GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/3)\vert=(3^2-1)(3^2-3)$. It's like counting basis. You have $(3^2-1)$ choices for the first vector $v\neq 0$, the second vector $w$ should not be a multiple of the first one so you have $(3^2-3)$ choices.

Comment: So, the number of isomorphisms is the same as the number of bases for the vector space? 48? Why is this and how do I justify that this is the number of isomorphisms? Thanks!

Comment: Columns (or rows) of a matrix form a basis iff the matrix is invertible, this is why counting invertible matrices is like counting basis.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't come across automorphisms of groups so I'm not sure what this means. Thanks though!

Comment: @LaurenHayes  No need for groups, i miss understood what you  r looking for. I've edited the comment.